# crm 2011 solution components belongs to Active Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, I noticed that if a change (customization) is not published, it belongs to 'Active Solution'.

1. In what cases does a solution component belong to the 'Active Solution'?
2. Does the 'Active Solution' hold all unpublished solution components?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Active Solution is the composite of all your installed solutions and represents the complete functionality of the system.  So to answer your questions:

1) All solution components belong to the Active Solution

2) I think all unpublished customizations belong to only the Active Solution until they are published, at which point they will belong to both the Active Solution and any specific solutions they are created under.

This is based upon a bit of conjecture and if anyone can verify or refute this that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked solution component related tables, it is not clear.